# How to receive private messages from the stream using Socket.IO in .Net Core 3.0

Tags: socket.io, serversocket, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to receive private meesages from SocketIO stream. I have IP address but I am getting problem in connection. Also, if connection will happen then also I have to authorize the connection using token then only I can get the messages. I dont how to implement this as I am vey much New to this thing.
I have tried with the following code from the stack overflow but no luck yet.

Also, can anybody tell me which library is best to use:

1. SocketIO4Net.Client
2. SocketIOClientDotNet

I am using 2nd one.

```
var socket = IO.Socket("myip");

    socket.On("xx", async (data) =>
        {                                                              
            var test = await Update(data.ToString());
        });
```

Can anybody help me on this. I am .net server side developer.Thanks in advance!!